# Custom Xubuntu window shortcuts don't work on startup

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, shortcut-keys

I recently installed Xubuntu 20.04 on a new laptop.

I like to use <Ctrl>+<Alt>+K as a shortcut for maximizing window size and I added this shortcut in the usual way; see picture below (in Dutch, but hopefully clear enough).

[image]

On startup, however, the shortcut does not work.  If I go back into the setting window above, click on the maximize window option and re-type that I want <Ctrl>+<Alt>+K to be the corresponding shortcut, then it will resume working again for a while.  However, it does not persist after a re-start and sometimes it stops working after a period even without re-starting.

Any idea what is happening here?

**Edit:** Perhaps a related issue is that the <Ctrl>+<Alt>+T shortcut for the terminal also doesn't work after startup, initially, but will typically start working after a few minutes.

Comment: but is the custom shortcut listed after startup?

Comment: Yes, sorry, should have said.  After startup, the maximize window shortcut is still listed as being Ctrl+Alt+K, but it's not functional.  If I click on the shortcut and just hit Ctrl+Alt+K to set it again anyway, it will start working.  Very weird

Comment: it's a bug then.

Comment: I assumed as much.  Looking for a workaround